# Asp MVC 5 - ModelState is Invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel, modelstate

I have the following view model:

```
public class CreateCaseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Post Content")]
    [UIHint("ForumEditor"), AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    // some other dropdown properties

}
```

The following controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 [ValidateInput(false)]
 public ActionResult Create(CreateCaseViewModel viewModel, FormCollection collection)
 {

        // Re-populate dropdowns 
        viewModel.Categories = _unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.GetCategories();


        viewModel.Subject = collection["Subject"];
        viewModel.PostContent = collection["Description"];

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        } 
        catch (DataException  dex  )
        {
           throw new ApplicationException("Something :", dex);
        }

        return View(viewModel);    

 }
```

I am manually assigning the value to PostContent from a value in FormCollection as you can see from code above. However I still keep getting modelstate is invalid - I'm returned back to the view with the validation error saying `The Post Content field is required'

Why is modelstate invalid?

Comment: Why are you using FormCollection and manually assigning it ? Create a new property called Description in your view model and let the model binding takes care of it for you

Comment: @Shyju Its a dynamic form where the form structure is stored as xml so I cant create a dedicated view model as I don't know how many fields are going to be on the form or what they are called. However there are some mandatory fields such as Subject and PostContent and I want to map them to the view model. The fields will be soted as name value pairs in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form the model binder will read the posted request data and map it to your method parameter. After that model validation framework will do the validation. It does not look at your FormCollection for doing this. So in your case, your model validation is failing because as per your view model it is expecting a value for `PostContent` property and it is not available there. Your action method code where you are setting the value of it gets executed later ( by this time model validation already occurred).

Your options are, either standardize the input element name with your view model property name (rename the `PostContent` to `Description` or vice versa)

```
public class CreateCaseViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Post Content")]
    [UIHint("ForumEditor"), AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }    

}
```

Now let the model binder maps the request body to your view model parameter. Remove the manual assignment from the FormCollection in your action method

**Or** you can probably create a new [custom model binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) which does the custom mapping for you (same as what you did in your action method).

I would go with option one. Let the default model binder takes care of it.

Comment: is the binding case sensitive i.e.  `public string Description { get; set; }` map to an element name `description`?

Comment: it is case in sensitive. `description` should bind fine to `Description`

Answer (score 1):

The model is validated before it is passed to your controller action. Modifying the model does not change that.

You need to call `ModelState.Clear()` followed by `Controller.TryValidateModel(model)` to re-validate the model and reset the IsValid property.

Comment: so how come its validating the `Subject` field? Is it because on the form I have a field called `Subject` where as I don't have a field called `PostContent` in the actual form. If I was to rename the `Description` field to `PostContent` inside the form that should work as well?

Comment: Nice one Philip. Your tip got me back on the right track.

Comment: The model is validated, but your required field PostContent is empty. So IsValid is set to false. You then set PostContent, but that does not alter any of the validation. You have to re-validate the model manually in order to change the IsValid setting.